# How can I make Appclip work with Enterprise distribution and AppStore distribution in the same time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-enterprise, apple-appclips

I know "Enterprise distribution isn’t available to App Clips" form Apple's document, but our company's internal testing is using "enterprise distribution" as it fits our team. We can accept the internal distribution without Appclip, and  upload to testflight to test Appclip feature, so we want to keep the Appclip code in the codebase.

Is there a way to turn off Appclip in the Xcode project so we can archive it using Enterprise account?

When Fastlane archiving our app, we always getting this error:

```
error: Provisioning profile "xxx" doesn't support the On Demand Install Capable capability. (in target 'xxxAppClip' from project 'XXX')
error: Provisioning profile "XXX" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.on-demand-install-capable and com.apple.developer.parent-application-identifiers entitlements. (in target 'XXXAppClip' from project 'XXX')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with TestFlight, which should fit your requirement if you finally publish to apple store.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build or distribute App Clip with Enterprise certs. And also, the app identifier of your App Clip on App Store website can only be generated within Individual/Company Apple Developer Enrollment ($99 account).